# Is there a way to control when MKMapView loads data

Tags: ios, mkmapview, mapkit

Background: after my app has started, it downloads data for a tableview. At the same time it also loads data for the mapview - which comes across the data download when there are bad network conditions.

I would like to disable the map-data download until the other data has finished with downloading. Is there a way to do so? Didn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a **NSOperationQueue** instead and add one operation after the other, so it will download map data once table data download is already finished.

Comment: Thanks Pablo. Sure, but what is the parameter to set to "start" the data download for the map?

Comment: What do you mean by "download data for the map", do you mean to render? I though you were downloading some data for then show it in the map, no the map rendering. There is no way to tell the map to start rendering later, the only possible way it's to add the map to the view after downloading your data. Map starts loading once added to the view.